# How to select individual values from an array of records in snowflake

Tags: loops, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have an array of records in my snowflake table like:

```
select  * from dw.public.arr_table;


['val1'\t'val2'\t'val3'\t'val4'\t'val5'\t, 'val6'\t'val7'\t'val8'\t'val9'\t'val10'\t ]
['val1'\t'val2'\t'val3'\t'val4'\t'val5'\t, 'val6'\t'val7'\t'val8'\t'val9'\t'val10'\t ]
['val1'\t'val2'\t'val3'\t'val4'\t'val5'\t, 'val6'\t'val7'\t'val8'\t'val9'\t'val10'\t ]
['val1'\t'val2'\t'val3'\t'val4'\t'val5'\t, 'val6'\t'val7'\t'val8'\t'val9'\t'val10'\t ]
```

Each record is an array. How can I iterate through each array and select val1 & val6?
I expect the result to be:

col1 col2
val1 val6

val1 & val6 are under column col1 and col2 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

The way you formatted your sample data doesn't make sense. I assume you want

```
select split(['val1\tval2\tval3\tval4\tval5\t', 'val6\tval7\tval8\tval9\tval10\t'][0],'\t')[0]::varchar as col1,
       split(['val1\tval2\tval3\tval4\tval5\t', 'val6\tval7\tval8\tval9\tval10\t'][1],'\t')[0]::varchar as col2
```

Answer (score 0):

so if your data is "an string encoded array with tab separated values", then something like this CTE recreates your data:

```
with cte(col) as (
    select parse_json(column1) from values    
    ('["val1\tval2\tval3\tval4\tval5\t", "val6\tval7\tval8\tval9\tval10\t"]')
)
```

this gives us an array with two entries, if we always have two entries, we can access these can hard coded array indexes:

```
select 
    col
    ,col[0] as a0
    ,col[1] as a1
from cte
```

giving:

| COL | A0 | A1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [ "val1\tval2\tval3\tval4\tval5\t", "val6\tval7\tval8\tval9\tval10\t" ] | "val1\tval2\tval3\tval4\tval5\t" | "val6\tval7\tval8\tval9\tval10\t" |

we can then split those strings into there own array, but given you only wanted the first value we can use [STRTOK](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/strtok.html) as just take the first value:

```
select 
    col
    ,col[0] as a0
    ,col[1] as a1
    ,strtok(a0, '\t', 1) as a00
    ,strtok(a1, '\t', 1) as a10
from cte
```

| COL | A0 | A1 | A00 | A10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [ "val1\tval2\tval3\tval4\tval5\t", "val6\tval7\tval8\tval9\tval10\t" ] | "val1\tval2\tval3\tval4\tval5\t" | "val6\tval7\tval8\tval9\tval10\t" | val1 | val6 |

This feels like what you are asking for, if not, feel free to comment about to the gap in the problem/need.